# Printing json instead of redirecting

Tags: php, json, laravel

The following code is printing the json instead of redirecting to the url..

view.php

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('/login') }}',
                data: data,
                method: 'POST',
                timeout: 15000, // sets timeout to 5000 = 5 seconds
                success: function(data){
                    //$('#form-login').fadeOut();
                    $('.loader').fadeOut();
                    //$(form).submit();
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                    $('#submitReg').show();
                    $('#submitLogin').show();
                },
```

controller.php

```
    if(auth()->user()->isRole('admin')){

    return response() -> json([
            'url'           => '/panel/gestion',
        ], 200); 

    }
```

returning in the window browser (not just in the developer panel)

> {"url":"/panel/gestion"}

I don't understand this behaviour as there are no any dd('') or var_dump code..

What I have wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Add the following line before your `location.href`: `data = JSON.parse(data);` Does this have any effect?

Comment: retrun response(); when acess it prints url!

Comment: @TrOnNe  What version of Laravel are you using (for reference)?

Comment: are you using a form?

Comment: "I don't understand this behaviour as there are no any dd('') or var_dump code.." you are returning json (`return response()->json(...)`) .. it is text, your browser knows how to render text

Comment: @commanderZiltoid I didn't try that, but suddenly my code worked without doing anything, which makes me inconfortable as it might occur again.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi it was working in the past, and I saw several examples on internet using the same return response, do you have any other alternative?

Comment: @RoboBear Laravel 5.3.30

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I'm using a form and my browser knows how to render text, but why want to render text when I'm telling him to use that info to redirect?

Comment: So, as my code it's now working, I'm not sure if the problem is caused by the browser (Chrome) aka the code is wrong at some point causing undesired behaviours in the explorer. 

BTW thanks all for your interest :)

Comment: who says that javascript is actually running? sounds like the form is just submitting like normal to its action.   you can easily check if this is the case ...

Comment: @lagbox well, its usually working, or at least it's not deactivated. It seems the browser renders before any js is loaded

Comment: Do you have your ajax call inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){//code here});`?

Comment: yes, it's very frustrating. Same code, and sometimes works, sometimes not. This is the view code https://codepaste.net/mrya86 line 339